# Save browser data in CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I have an Windows Form Application which utilises CefSharp.
A while ago I used a chunk of code that saves the state of the browser such as login details etc so that the user does not have to log in multiple times.

This is the code I used:

```
    private static bool _hasRun;

        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        if (!_hasRun)
        {
            Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings { CachePath = "MyCachePath", PersistSessionCookies = true });
        }
        _hasRun = true;
        string cache_dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\CEF";
        settings.CachePath = cache_dir;
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("persist_session_cookies", "1");
        string link = Domain;
        chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(link);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(chrome);
        chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

This code runs fine in my old application but when using this on my most recent app I receive this error message:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You've used a relative path and an absolute path is now required. As the exception says you can use Path.GetFullPath to get an absolute path from a relative one. Is there something unclear about the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide a full path.

> non-absolute: "MyCachepath"

> absolute: "C:\users\username\documents\MyCachepath"

**why did it work in older projects?**

Some project types and versions automaticallly translate an relative path into an absolute path like so:

> `environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\MyCachepath"`

Comment: Chromium changes now require an absolute path, previously using a relative path would have worked. Nothing to do with automatically translated paths.